# Can't get POST data from Django form

Tags: django, forms, post

I have a form involving just two `textarea`s and I'm trying to POST them. However, I'm having difficulty trying to get the POST data from my view. Here's what I have so far in my template:

```
{% block title %}
<form method="post">
    <strong>Title:</strong>
    <div>
        <textarea contenteditable id="id-title" name="title"></textarea>
    </div>
{% endblock title %}

{% block description %}
    <strong>Description:</strong>
    <div>
        <textarea contenteditable id="id-description" name="description"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock description %}

<button class="btn-primary" id="ok" url="{% url 'publish' id=id %}" type="submit">Publish</button>
```

view:

```
@ajax
@csrf_exempt
@admin_required
def publish(request, id):
    title = request.POST.get('title')
    desc = request.POST.get('description')
    print title
    print desc
    ...
```

But `title` and `desc` turn out to be `None`. My `publish` function is also an ajax function that does some other stuff when the button is pressed.

Comment: have you tried without `@admin_required`?

Comment: Well, this function should only be performed by a user who is an admin, so I wouldn't want to remove that decorator.

Comment: Do you not want to solve the problem? To do that troubleshoot by stripping out your function?

Comment: Removing the @admin_required decorator does not help. `title` and `desc` both still return `None`.

Comment: I'd strip out all the decorator, try with regular post. if that works, add on decorator, add on ajax...you get the idea. what you have post is too trivial and nothing seems wrong.

Comment: After stripping all decorators, `title` and `desc` still both return `None`.

Comment: there you go then, start from there.

Comment: If this form is being submitted by an Ajax script, it's likely that the problem lies there; you should post that code.

Answer (score 0):

Try altering your form with `action`, and moving your submit inside the form, e.g.:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'publish' id=id %}">                                             
{% block title %}                                                                                   
<strong>Title:</strong>                                                                         
<div>                                                                                           
    <textarea contenteditable id="id-title" name="title"></textarea>                            
</div>                                                                                          
{% endblock title %}                                                                                

{% block description %}                                                                             
<strong>Description:</strong>                                                                   
<div>                                                                                           
    <textarea contenteditable id="id-description" name="description"></textarea>                
</div>                                                                                          
{% endblock description %}                                                                          
<input id="ok" type="submit">                                                                   
</form>
```